# How to freeze out all PyQt4 user inputs until backend process has finished?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, modality

I'm trying to avoid forking errors that are occurring when the user starts messing around with the GUI while backend threads are computing (for instance, moving through other tabs while a progress bar is running).

Is there a way to completely prohibit their interference with the frontend while backend processes are running?

Comment: Show a modal progress dialog with no cancel button (and also override its `closeEvent` to prevent e.g. closing with Alt-F4).

Comment: If I already have progress bars in the main window itself, do I have to open up a new window with new progress bars? Is there a way to have this window running but hidden?

Comment: Or just disable the ui elements that shouldn't be interacted with while the background process is running. But then again, what is the point in running it in the background if the user can't continue interacting with the ui?

Comment: I'd honestly love if they could keep moving around the GUI while backend is running. I'm getting a bunch of "FORKING" errors on mac though when tried.

Comment: I don't see how anyone can really answer your question unless you provide a [mcve]. Also, if this is mac-specific, you should state that clearly in your question and give versions of all the relevant libraries you are using. I have no idea what you mean by "forking erros" (unless that was just a typo ;-)

Comment: I used a workaround for now based on your advice, and ended up just disabling all of the ui elements until the process finishes. It works for what I need, thanks! :)